# Selection of middle element in merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting

For a given merge sort code below:

```
void merge(int a[], int bottom, int top, int mid){
    int i = bottom;
    int j = mid+1;
    int k = bottom;
    int c[50];

    while (i <= mid&&j <= top){
         if(a[i]<=a[j]){
         c[k] = a[i];
         i++;
         k++;
         }
     else{
         c[k] = a[j];
         j++;
         k++;
         }
    }

    while (i <= mid){
     c[k] = a[i];
     k++;
     i++;
    }

    while (j <= top){
     c[k] = a[j];
     k++;
     j++;
    }

    for (int i = bottom; i < k; i++){
     a[i] = c[i];   
    }
}

void mergesort(int a[], int bottom, int top){
    if(bottom < top){
     int mid = (bottom+top)/2;
     mergesort(a, bottom, mid);
     mergesort(a, mid+1, top);
     merge(a, bottom, top, mid);
    }
}
```

If change the mergesort calling to

```
mergesort(a, bottom, mid-1);
mergesort(a, mid, top);
```

It will cause run time error.

From the aspect of algorithm, I didn't see any difference. Could some one point out what's wrong with the change?

Comment: Related: Nearly every "sample" on mergesort pseudo-code and/or non-C/C++ implementations you find is great in theory, but lack in practice by using a low and high fencepost element index. It isn't needed, as the languages support *pointer arithmetic*. I.e. It is *far* easier to do this in C or C++ using a base pointer, a sequence length, and pointer-arithmetic when recursing. [example setup](http://pastebin.com/mjG1GLhi).

Comment: BTW, `int c[50]` looks dangerous. Worse, you can easily compute how many elements `c` should have, so there are no excuses. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say bottom is 0, and top is 1 because you called `mergesort(a, 0, 1)`. Then mid = (0+1)/2 = 0. Then mid-1 = -1. Then you are calling `mergesort(a, 0, -1)` and `mergesort(a, 0, 1)` (notice...this is the call we started with). The first call will return because it doesn't match the `bottom < top` condition but the second one is an infinite recursion.

If you'll notice, this problem applies to all calls of the form `mergesort(a, n, n + 1)`, and because mergesort is a divide and conquer type algorithm, you'll be making these kinds of calls quite frequently.